# Is there a standard/recommended way (or library) in android I should perform GET, PUT, POST and DELETE requests with Kotlin?

Tags: android, post, kotlin, get, put

I'm getting started with Android development and I wanted to create an app that would perform some http queries on some publicly exposed API.

As I come from an Angular 6 environment and there's an standard `HttpClient` library to use I want to know if it's the same with Android using Kotlin.

Although I appreciate suggestions on libraries I would rather use "standard" libraries if there are any.

Comment: volley and retrofit are the best libraries to call the restful service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no standard Kotlin HTTP library. But there are [Ktor](https://ktor.io/). It is HTTP framework written on Kotlin and supported by JetBrains. It can be used as HTTP client on Android. You can find samples on Ktor's website and GitHub. Take into account that Ktor is beta.

But as mentioned Zahoor Saleem you can use HTTP libraries written on Java.
Most popular is [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) with [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/).